# Printing a pattern of alphanumeric numbers in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I create a temp table in a sql select statement which will hold list of alphanumeric numbers.

Select yearlyQuarters from temp;

```
2023Q1
2022Q4
2022Q3
2022Q2
2022Q1
2021Q4
2021Q3
2021Q2
2021Q1
......
```

I tried creating the temp data as

```
WITH t(n) AS (
   SELECT 1900 from dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n+1 from t WHERE n < 3000)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

I am not sure how can I add the quarter details to the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cross-join the result with the quarters. For example:

```
WITH t(n) AS (
   SELECT 2000 from dual
   UNION ALL
   SELECT n+1 from t WHERE n < 2003)
SELECT t.n || 'Q' || y.q
FROM t
cross join (
  select 1 as q from dual
  union all select 2 from dual
  union all select 3 from dual  
  union all select 4 from dual  
) y
```

Result:

```
T.N||'Q'||Y.Q
-------------
2000Q1
2000Q2
2000Q3
2000Q4
2001Q1
2001Q2
2001Q3
2001Q4
2002Q1
2002Q2
2002Q3
2002Q4
2003Q1
2003Q2
2003Q3
2003Q4
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_vilTb_H).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the date `1900-01-01` and repeatedly add 3 months to get the next quarter and then use `TO_CHAR` to format it:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1900-01-01', 3 * LEVEL - 3),
         'YYYY"Q"Q'
       ) AS yearly_quarters
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1900-01-01', 3 * LEVEL - 3) <= SYSDATE;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GjcGAHkj)